# Could not authenticate Google account through PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer in a Simple Script For Send Email's Through Gmail, and I'm getting an this error (I'm sure that the email and  password combination is correct):

> !-- 2020-12-02 14:13:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
> 2020-12-02 14:13:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
> 2020-12-02 14:13:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
> 2020-12-02 14:13:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
> SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Allow less secure apps is ON

This is the way I implement the phpMailer

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require './mailer/autoload.php';

$msg = "";
 
$mail = new PHPMailer();

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT; 
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.google.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = '********@gmail.com'; 
    $mail->Password = '********';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 25; 
    $mail->CharSet= 'UTF-8';
    $mail->setFrom('*******@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress($_POST["mail"]);

    $mail->isHTML(true); 
    $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $mail->Body = '<h2>E-mail</h2>';
    $mail->AltBody = $_POST["content"];

    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $msg = "An Error has Ocurr";
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

SMTP port 25 is not used with TLS, you should use port 587 for TLS/STARTTLS or 456 for SSL. And it seems that you've also used the incorrect host URL, which should be `smtp.google.com`. The required configuration is stated here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229.

So you should probably change:

```php
...
$mail->Host = 'smtp.google.com';
$mail->Port = 25;
...
```

To:

```php
...
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; 
...
```

Depending on your situation, it might not be best practice to use Google's default SMTP. It is OK for personal use, but if you want to send more automated emails, you should look for other options. The default Google SMTP is strictly rate limited for example.

First of all, [Google SMTP Relay](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491) yields a little more configurability if you need it.

When you really want to send automated or bulk emails, you should look into a provider specifically for this. It is not what the Google SMTP servers are made for and you will quickly notice by emails not being sent out or delivered properly.

Comment: still didn't work, I have changed the port with its corresponding SMTPSecure attribute and this is the new error ( the same for both )

Comment: 2020-12-02 14:44:32 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)<br>
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: I just updated the answer as I noticed the host was also incorrect, did you change that as well?

Comment: I will check it now

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you actually read the error message and took the advice it gives you, by reading the guide it links to.

First of all, you're only showing client debug output, so you can't see what the server is saying, and so you can't tell what's going on, [as the docs say](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#enabling-debug-output). Do this:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
```

Without seeing what that says, you're working blind.

That said, you get kicked out immediately after EHLO, and the only thing you have said is:

```
2020-12-02 14:13:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
```

Unfortunately this is untrue, and I'd guess that gmail is calling you out on it. `localhost` is by definition not an internet routable address, and any reverse lookup on the name will never match the IP you are connecting from, which is *not* `localhost`. If that is happening automatically, override it manually by setting the client host explicitly:

```
$mail->Helo = 'myhost.example.com';
```

While RFCs mandate port 587 for SMTP+STARTTLS, gmail supports it on port 25 too, and you can see that your STARTTLS command is working successfully, so that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

use port 587

```
 $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug    = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure   = 'tls';
    $mail->Host         = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port         = 587;
    $mail->Username     = '********@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password     = '********';
```